# Consumir WebService SOAP con GeneXus 18 de DGI - eFactura

Tags: genexus, genexus18

Buenas comunidad ¿Cómo están? He estado tratando de consumir los WebServices de DGI para consultar las facturas recibidas:

https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6440/efactura/ws_consultas.wsdl

Documentación al respecto:
https://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-externos-consultas-pdf?es

En SOAPUI me funciona correctamente, sin embargo no he tenido éxito al intentar consumirlo desde GeneXus 18. Importé el WSDL, me crea los SDT y el objeto externo, estoy utilizando WSSecurity:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?44552,WSSecurity+Data+Type

y location:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6981,Location+data+type

A continuación un ejemplo del código:

```
//Encryptation
&WsSecurityKeyStore.Password    = "12345678"
&WsSecurityKeyStore.Type        = WSSecurityKeyStore.JKS
&WsSecurityKeyStore.Source      = "C:\Certificados\prueba.jks"
&wsEncryption.Alias             = "prueba123"
&wsEncryption.keyIdentifierType = WsSecurity.BINARY_SECURITY_TOKEN
&wsEncryption.Keystore          = &WsSecurityKeyStore

&wssecurity.Encryption = &wsEncryption
&wssecurity.ExpirationTimeout = 5
 
//Signature
&wssecurity.Signature.Alias     = "prueba123"
&wssecurity.Signature.keyIdentifierType = WsSecurity.BINARY_SECURITY_TOKEN
&wssecurity.Signature.Keystore.Password = "12345678"
&wssecurity.Signature.Keystore.Type     = WSSecurityKeyStore.JKS
&wssecurity.Signature.Keystore.Source   = "C:\Certificados\prueba.jks"
&wssecurity.Signature.CanonicalizationAlgorithm = "CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE"
&wssecurity.Signature.SignatureAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"
&wssecurity.Signature.Digest = "DigestMethod.SHA256"

&location         = getLocation("WS_eFactura_Consultas")
&location.WSSecurity    = &wssecurity
&location.Host          = "www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy"
&location.BaseUrl       = "/efactura/ws_consultas"
&location.Port          = 6440
&location.CancelOnError = 2
&location.secure    = 1
&location.Timeout   = 1
&location.AuthenticationMethod = 1

&WS_eFactura_ConsultasConsultaRUCEmisores.Filtro_eFacRUCEmisorAudFchHora.FromString('10-17-2023 01:00:00')
&WS_eFactura_ConsultasRucEmisoresMail_RucEmisoresMailItem = &WS_eFactura_Consultas.EFACCONSULTARRUCEMISORES(&WS_eFactura_ConsultasConsultaRUCEmisores)
&Error = GetSOAPErr()
```

El jks y el alias son ficticios, pero cuento con uno.
El error que captura el GetSOAPErr() es el siguiente: `-10001 Connect to www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6440 [www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/190.64.1.5] failed: Connect timed out`
Agradecería si alguien me pudiera orientar.

Answer (score -1):

intenta hacerlo con el valor:

&location.Host = "efactura.dgi.gub.uy" // elimino del string 'www.'

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).